# Hibernate cannot find suitable driver for Derby in Spring MVC webapp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I wonder if anyone can explain to me why a Spring and Hibernate webapp works perfectly well in two environments but fails in another? I'm using `NetBeans 8.0.X` with `Tomcat 8.0.3.0` and `Apache Derby 10.X`.

My application's `dispatcherservlet` is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"       
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc                            
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd                           
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Uses annotations in classes for JavaBeans. XML is an alternative. -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />   

<!-- Base package. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="library" />    

<!-- Model. -->
<bean id="person" class="library.model.Person" />
<bean id="book" class="library.model.Book" />        

<!-- Spring Controllers. -->
<bean id="adminController" class="library.controller.admin.AdminController" />    
<bean id="personController" class="library.controller.PersonController" />      
<bean id="bookController" class="library.controller.BookController" /> 
<bean id="exceptionController" class="library.controller.ExceptionController" />     

<!-- Spring Interceptors. -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="clientInterceptor" class="library.interceptor.ClientInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- Spring Services. -->
<bean id="personServiceImpl" class="library.service.PersonServiceImpl" />    
<bean id="bookServiceImpl" class="library.service.BookServiceImpl" />      

<!-- Spring Repositories. -->
<bean id="personDAOImpl" class="library.dao.PersonDAOImpl" />    
<bean id="bookDAOImpl" class="library.dao.BookDAOImpl" />       

<!-- Spring Validators. -->
<bean id="personValidator" class="library.validator.PersonValidator" />    
<bean id="bookValidator" class="library.validator.BookValidator" />     

<!-- Spring ViewResolver. -->               
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>   

<!-- Spring MesssageSource. -->         
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename"> 
        <value>/WEB-INF/classes/messages</value>    
    </property>    
</bean>

<!-- Spring Properties file for Library. -->      
<bean id="propertiesFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location">  
         <value>classpath:library.properties</value>             
    </property>
</bean>      

<!-- Hibernate DataSource. -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">   
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />        
    <!--property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" /-->
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />            
</bean>   

<!-- Hibernate Interceptors. -->
<bean id="serverInterceptor" class="library.interceptor.ServerInterceptor" />

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory. -->    
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">    
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>                  
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>    
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>                     
           <!--prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSixDialect</prop-->
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>               

           <!-- What to do with the database schema. -->
           <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>    
           <!-- validate:    validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
                update:      update the schema.
                create:      creates the schema, destroying previous data.
                create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session. -->                 
        </props>            
    </property>                                                                                                                                
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <ref bean="serverInterceptor" />            
    </property>                                                                                                                                             
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>library.model</value>                
        </list>
    </property>          
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate TransactionManagment. -->
<tx:annotation-driven />                
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And the errors given when the application builds and fails in the one environment is:

```
WARN|01 07 2015|16 26 31|http-nio-8080-exec-73|org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl| - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library
INFO|01 07 2015|16 26 31|http-nio-8080-exec-73|org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect| - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSixDialect
INFO|01 07 2015|16 26 34|http-nio-8080-exec-73|org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder| - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
ERROR|01 07 2015|16 26 41|http-nio-8080-exec-73|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader| - Context initialization failed
```

Which is then causing the wiring of the dependencies to fail.

What do these messages mean?

The application is using `Spring 4.0.2` with `hibernate-core-4.3.10.jar`. All dependencies are identical between the three environments and a listing of them follows:

```
30 Jun 2015  20 26           445,288 antlr-2.7.7.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26             4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           160,519 commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            62,050 commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26         2,834,700 derby.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           582,639 derbyclient.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            75,311 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26         5,280,098 hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 27           113,371 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            38,605 jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           225,306 jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 27           228,552 jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26         1,074,275 jackson-databind-2.4.1.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           786,084 jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.13.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            76,551 jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           714,194 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           162,126 javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            57,183 jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            11,558 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 27            27,717 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            20,682 jstl-1.1.2.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26            15,071 jta-1.1.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           367,444 log4j-1.2.14.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 27            52,150 persistence-api-1.0.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 27            36,364 spring-annotation-base-1.0.2.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           352,730 spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           669,044 spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           974,272 spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           960,994 spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           204,780 spring-expression-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           419,614 spring-jdbc-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           366,844 spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           248,204 spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           665,015 spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           660,329 spring-webmvc-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
30 Jun 2015  20 26           393,259 standard-1.1.2.jar
```

Comment: You said it failed to compile. But error message is from runtime. When do you get error exactly? Could you also share your dependencies on both environment? Are you sure that your derby driver's jar in your class path?

Comment: The problem occurs just after the project has been compiled as part of running it. The dependencies are listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `derbyclient.jar` is not present in your lib, So please add this jar in your libraries. Download it from [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html)

Comment: `derbyclient.jar` is present in the dependencies.

Comment: then you should check for its compatible version.

Comment: The current versions of `derby.jar` and `derbyclient.jar` being used have been tested with the version of Derby from `JDK 1.7` and `1.8`. they seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about your connection string. Could you try it like this?

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">   
      property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:~/Library" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />            
</bean>
```

This will create a database named Library on $USER_HOME.

### Update

On default derby do not support connection string like `jdbc:derby://localhost/Libarary` . In order to connect a derby server over network you add `derbynet.jar` to your class path. You can find [additional info here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html).

Then you can use your default datasource definition.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">   
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />        
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />            
</bean>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it will create a new database, but I then have to amend things back to `<property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:~/Library" />`. This however fails to connect so I have to revert to `<property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library" />`

Comment: @MrMorgan I do not think derby supports jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library kind of connection strings. What is the location of Library database you try to connect?

Comment: If I use these settings without the embedded driver, and with `derbynet.jar`, `derbyrun,jar` and `derbytools.jar`, everything runs smoothly in a test environment. I will have to test this live tomorrow.

Comment: Even with these settings, the project fails to load just after compilation. What is wrong with this live platform?

Comment: @MrMorgan it is not compilation error. Its a runtime error. Are you sure there is a derby server on your production environment?

Comment: Yes there is an installation of Derby on the production server and it is being used as per the solution I posted. This is only a demonstration project so there is no problem with running NetBeans and Apache Tomcat from memory stick.